# laravel validation - check id exists in group performance

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a database table `items` which has a field called `team_id`. Users exist as part of a team.

I want to send a request with ~500 items like this:

```
{
   items: [
      {
         id: 5,
         name: "item 5",
         ...etc
      },
      {
         id: 6,
         name: "item 5",
         ...etc
      }
      ...etc
   ]
}
```

I want to check the all items are in the correct 'team', and reject the request if one item is not related to the user's 'team'. I can do this via:

```
'items.*.id' => ['required', 'exists:items,id,team_id,' . $team->id],
```

However this sends 500 database queries - checking each item individually, which increases my request execution time.

Is there a validation rule I can use which will execute a SQL 'IN' query, so that I can do this in one SQL query?

If I need to do a custom rule, how can I aggregate all the item ids into an array to pass to my custom rule?

Comment: Did you try the `in` validation rule? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-in. You'll have to load the acceptable values into an array (like `Item::pluck('team_id')` or similar), but that would reduce your DB calls from 500 to 1

Comment: Thanks. I used the `withValidator` function in the form request, run the custom rule and if the rule `passes()` then I add an error message.

Comment: It seems like you fixed your own question but forgot to answer your own question with what you found. Can you post the answer and mark it?

Comment: This assumption is incorrect @Wanjia. I’m looking for a Laravel validation rule, not a custom rule. The former is built into the framework, the latter you write yourself.

Comment: It's not because you're looking for an actual existing validation rule that you can't make your own if it where not to exists. I added an answer of my own validation rule and customized it to fit your needs too.

Answer (score 0):

This feature doesn't exists as of laravel 9.0.

You can however make your own [custom validation rules](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#custom-validation-rules).

Since I needed this for myself but not as extensive I have adjusted my own custom rule and extended to where it could be used in your case.

```php
class ExistsInRule implements Rule
{
    protected $subject;
    protected $column;
    protected $conditions;
    protected $notFound;

    public function __construct($subject, $column = 'id', $conditions = [])
    {
        $this->subject    = $subject;
        $this->column     = $column;
        $this->conditions = $conditions;
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $values): bool
    {
        $columnValues = $values;
        if (isset($values[0][$this->column])) {
            $columnValues = collect($values)->pluck($this->column);
        }

        $query = $this->subject::select($this->column);

        foreach ($this->conditions as $conditionKey => $conditionValue) {
            $query->where($conditionKey, $conditionValue);
        }

        $ids = $query->find($columnValues)->pluck($this->column);

        $this->notFound = collect($columnValues)->diff($ids);

        return $this->notFound->isEmpty();
    }

    public function message(): string
    {
        $conditionMessage = $this->conditions ? ' where ' . str_replace('=', ' is ', http_build_query($this->conditions, '', ', and where ')) : '';

        return 'The selected :attribute are invalid: ' . $this->notFound->implode(', ') . $conditionMessage . '.';
    }
}
```

The error message would be as followed:

> The selected Items are invalid: 1, 2, 3 where team_id is 9.

When you only have an array of ids you need to check (my case) your custom request class would look like this:

```php
class CustomRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'items' => [
                'required',
                'array',
                'min:1',
                new ExistsInRule(Item::class, 'id', ['team_id' => $team->id])
            ],
            'items.*.id' => [
                'required',
                'numeric',
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

When you only have an array of ids you need to check (my case):

```php
'item_ids' => [
    'required',
    'array',
    'min:1',
    new ExistsInRule(Item::class)
],
```